# Task vs Thread: на каком ядре

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl, task

Про Task:

> Данная библиотека позволяет распараллелить задачи и выполнять их сразу
>   на ***нескольких процессорах***, если на целевом компьютере имеется
>   несколько ядер. Кроме того, упрощается сама работа по созданию новых
>   потоков. Поэтому начиная с .NET 4.0. рекомендуется использовать именно
>   TPL и ее классы для создания многопоточных приложений, хотя
>   стандартные средства и класс Thread по-прежнему находят широкое
>   применение.

Источник: [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.1.php)

---

Изначально кол-во потоков в пуле потоков равно числу ядер процессора. Вопрос: каждый поток из потока пулов будет выполняться на "своем" ядре?


А как дела обстоят с обычными потоками - `Thread` (понимаю, что `Task` - более высокая абстракция `Thread`)? Новый `Thread` может выполняться как на ядре, где выполняется главный поток, так и на другом ядре, т.е. не гарантирует выполнение на новом ядре?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В цитате явно смесь процессоров и ядер. Но распараллеливаются обычно по ядрам, а эти ядра могут принадлежать разным процессорам.

> Изначально кол-во потоков в пуле потоков равно числу ядер процессора.

на усмотрение библиотеки.

> Вопрос: каждый поток из потока пулов будет выполняться на "своем" ядре?

можно сделать так, что бы каждый поток исполнялся только на своем ядре (осознанно привязав их), но так обычно не делают - планировщик ОС обычно несколько умнее и будет их разбрасывать по ядрам по своему разумению.

> А как дела обстоят с обычными потоками - Thread (понимаю, что Task - более высокая абстракция Thread)?

Да, Task - абстракция, которая прячет от программиста детали. Просто таска, это функция, которая выполняется внутри потока. Синхронизация, очереди и получения результата прячутся библиотекой.

> Новый Thread может выполняться как на ядре, где выполняется главный поток, так и на новом?

Там, где будет удобнее ОС разместить его. Более того, поток может "гулять" по ядрам.

Comment: Просто в цитате меня смутило, что делается акцент, что Task позволяет распараллелить задачи и выполнять на разных ядрах... Как будто, создав "пачку" Thread'ов, логика изменится...

Comment: Если создать тысячи Task, то они станут в очередь и ThreadPool их будет аккуратно исполнять, оптимально нагрузив проц. Если создать тысячи тредов, то скорее все посыпется или проц только тем и будет заниматься, что переключать потоки.

Comment: просто во всех своих проектах (и рабочих в том числе) использовал Thread'ы, так как исторически сложилось, понимая, что желательнее использовать таски. Сейчас решил в этой теме разобраться детально. То есть можно сказать, что таски куда более "интеллектуальны", нежели обычные Thread'ы?

Comment: нет, они просто более высокоуровневые. Если тредами владеете хорошо, сделаете код не хуже (но может быть придется пописать немного). Если треды знаете плохо, то таски могут сильно упростить код и ускорить разработку.

Comment: благодарю за ответ